Kubernetes Horizontal Pod Autoscaling (HPA) for specific container in the pod
In our deployment, there are 4 containers in the pod. We have defined the resource limits (CPU and memory) only for container-1. The metrics server is installed in the cluster.
Our requirement is to apply Horizontal Pod Autoscaling (HPA) with the following requirements. :

Need to check both CPU and Memory for HPA
Need to apply HPA (calculate memory and CPU) only for container-1 in the pod.

When we used following HPA yaml, it checked both cpu and memory. But it consider all containers in the pod. Because when applying, it gave us an error. Therefore, In this method we had to provide resource (cpu, memory) limits for other 3 containers as well. Then it properly showed the percentage of the current memory and cpu usage.
Error:

The HPA was unable to compute the replica count: failed to get cpu utilisation: missing request for cpu in container container-2 of Pod test-pod

apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
  kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
  metadata:
    annotations:
      autoscaling.alpha.kubernetes.io/metrics: '[{"type":"Resource","resource":{"name":"memory","targetAverageUtilization":75}}]'
    name: test-hpa
    namespace: ns
  spec:
    maxReplicas: 5
    minReplicas: 2
    scaleTargetRef:
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      kind: Deployment
      name: test-pod
    targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 65

The issue here is it doesn't only consider container-1 in the pod.

Is there a way that we can give a specific container in the hpa yaml
fulfilling the mentioned requirements?
Also, can we apply HPA without providing resource limits (CPU and
memory) to the other 3 containers in the pod?

I've tried several HPA yamls but it didn't fulfil the both requirements.
Also note that "apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2" is not working in our cluster because of the k8 version.

It's often a better practice to run only one container in a Pod, since you can separately control the replica count of each component and you don't hit conflicts like this.  Can you break up the Deployment into smaller pieces?

After trying several methods the following code worked, and was able to get both memory and cpu in the pod and the container.
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  annotations:
    autoscaling.alpha.kubernetes.io/metrics: |
      [
        {
          "type": "Resource",
          "resource": {
            "name": "memory",
            "targetAverageUtilization": 75
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "ContainerResource",
          "ContainerResource": {
            "name": "cpu",
            "container": "container-1",
            "targetAverageUtilization": 65
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "ContainerResource",
          "ContainerResource": {
            "name": "memory",
            "container": "container-1",
            "targetAverageUtilization": 75
          }
        }
      ]
  name: test-hpa
  namespace: ns
spec:
  maxReplicas: 5
  minReplicas: 2
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: test-pod
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 65

In here the following block in the annotation provide the memory metrics for the pod:
{
  "type": "Resource",
  "resource": {
    "name": "memory",
    "targetAverageUtilization": 75
  }
}

CPU metrics for the pod provided by:
targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 65
And the cpu and memory will be provided by following block in the annotation.
{
      "type": "ContainerResource",
      "ContainerResource": {
        "name": "cpu",
        "container": "container-1",
        "targetAverageUtilization": 65
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "ContainerResource",
      "ContainerResource": {
        "name": "memory",
        "container": "container-1",
        "targetAverageUtilization": 75
      }
    }

This provides the usage when I describe the hpa.
kubectl describe hpa -n ns


Metrics:
( current / target )   resource memory on pods  (as a percentage of
request):                                 63% (5497292117333m) / 75%
resource cpu of container "container-1" on pods  (as a percentage of
request):     0% (17m) / 65%   resource memory of container
"container-1" on pods  (as a percentage of request):  124%
(2673916586666m) / 75%   resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of
request):                                    1% (47m) / 65%

Thanks for your input @Zhakyp! It helped me resolve some issues. Hope this helps someone else too. This may not be the best way to do this. But only this worked for our k8 version (1.29).

Kubernetes official documentation

The HorizontalPodAutoscaler API also supports a container metric source where the HPA can track the resource usage of individual containers across a set of Pods, in order to scale the target resource. This lets you configure scaling thresholds for the containers that matter most in a particular Pod. For example, if you have a web application and a sidecar container that provides logging, you can scale based on the resource use of the web application, ignoring the sidecar container and its resource use.


If you revise the target resource to have a new Pod specification with a different set of containers, you should revise the HPA spec if that newly added container should also be used for scaling. If the specified container in the metric source is not present or only present in a subset of the pods then those pods are ignored and the recommendation is recalculated.
Algorithm for more details about the calculation. To use container resources for autoscaling define a metric source as follows:
If you do not specify a CPU limit for a Container, then one of these situations applies:

type: ContainerResource
containerResource:
  name: cpu
  container: application
  target:
    type: Utilization
    averageUtilization: 60

To use container resources for autoscaling define a metric source as follows, an example where the HPA controller scales the target such that the average utilization of the cpu in the application container of all the pods is 60%.
Additional info with algorithm used by HPA
If you do not specify a CPU limit
The Container has no upper bound limit on the CPU resources it can use. The Container can use all of the CPU resources available on the Node where the pod is running. So, in your case, it will be the second option which you have specified in your question: as much as is left on the node/namespace.
Normally, the Kubernetes Cluster Administrator defines the limit for each namespace in the cluster. So, the Container is running in a namespace that has a default CPU limit, and the Container is automatically assigned the default limit.
Resource Quotas should be defined for each Namespace, which comes in handy to get rid of pods that don't have resource requests or limits and are eating up all the resources. This means you cannot schedule the pod until you specify the resource requirements for that pod in a particular namespace, and this is recommended as best practice
for more information, you can read this documentation

I've also tried 'type: ContainerResource' already. But the thing is, it's for CPU. How can we apply that for the memory?

For memory, you can use the same as CPU, just change the name to memory like this. type: ContainerResource containerResource:   name: memory   container: application   target:     type: Utilization     averageUtilization: 60
I hope it works.

I checked like this. But it's not showing the memory. And I'm getting these errors in the startup. K8 version we used is 1.29. Errors:
W0510 03:29:39.197088  810156 warnings.go:70] unknown field "containerResource"
W0510 03:29:39.197117  810156 warnings.go:70] unknown field "spec.targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage"
W0510 03:29:39.197123  810156 warnings.go:70] unknown field "type"

This is the code I used: >> apiVersion: autoscaling/v1  kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata: name: test-hpa  namespace: ns
spec: scaleTargetRef: apiVersion: apps/v1 kind: Deployment name: test-pod
minReplicas: 5  maxReplicas: 2  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 65  targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage: 75
type: ContainerResource
containerResource: name: cpu  container: container-1  target: type: Utilization averageUtilization: 65
containerResource:  name: memory  container: container-1  target: type: Utilization averageUtilization: 75
